# i have a problem when i am going to sign up with google in my app they show me fail to parse user profile message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

hii everyone i have error in my node js app when i am trying to signup with google at that time they throw me an error message like  "fail to parse user profile message" i am using passport for authentication and passport-google-auth20 for sign up with google

here are my code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const ejs=require("ejs");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
var session = require('express-session');
const passport =require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')

const app=express();



app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'dirty little secret.',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }));

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB");

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User=new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);


passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL:"https://www.googleleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/login",function(req,res)
{
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/register",function(req,res)
{
    res.render("register");
});
app.get("/secrets",function(req,res)
{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("secrets");
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});

app.get("/logout",function(req,res,err)
{
    req.logout(function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
    
});

app.get("/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google",{scope:['email',"profile"]})
);

app.get( "/auth/google/secrets",
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {
        successRedirect: '/secrets',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
app.post("/register",function(req,res)
{
  User.register({username:req.body.username},req.body.password).then((user) => {
    passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect("/register");
  });
});
app.post("/login",function(req,res)
{
   const user=new User({
    username:req.body.username,
    password:req.body.password
   });
   req.login(user,function(err){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
            res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
    }
   });
   
});
app.listen(3000,function(req,res)
{
    console.log("server started on port 3000 :");
});
```

This is my error code image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWxBC.png)